# SVN merge loses files and code

Tags: svn, merge

I'm trying to merge trunk change-set into a branch, but have found out a lot of post-merge issues, including whole files that disappeared, and missing code blocks

I'm using SVN 1.6 for both clients and server.
Tried this with multiple clients - Eclipse, Netbeans and SVN - the result is the same.

Can someone advice how sort it out, and most important, prevent code loss?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A few questions. Was the branch created on 1.6? does it have a common ancestry with trunk? Are you merging everything from trunk? And can you show us the command you're using?

Comment: What is the svn command that is performing the merge? Are you merging a range of revisions, merging from repo to wc or from wc to wc?

Comment: Yes, the branch was created on 1.6, and was branched out from trunk.

I'm merging only the changes since the branching operation.

I'm using TortoiseSVN, and just telling it to merge a range.

Comment: Hey, I would try to use "reintegrate" instead of a normal merge... You have to know that, after you used "reintegrate", your branch will have to be closed... Hope this can help you a bit !

Comment: Have you renamed some files in branch or trunk?

Comment: What do you mean by re-integrate? Also I can't close the branch, as it's in development and needs the latest change-set from trunk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I used the CollabNet merge client which did the job automatically.

Apparently it was a clear case of me missing the revision numbers multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your issue is, but svn generally shouldn't lose anything unless you tell it to.  When in doubt, save an "svn diff" off to a file somewhere outside your repository until your changes are checked in as you wish.